# Por qué se usa "Dec-ia,ias,Ian, etc..." o "dije,dijo,..etc"

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, verbos, significado, historia

¿Cuándo uso el pretérito y el imperfecto para decir? Entiendo estos dos tensos en general. Pero cuando leo la Biblia en español, usa ambos con frecuencia para la persona que narra lo que sucedió. No puedo decir por qué se prefiere uno sobre el otro, casi parecen intercambiables como si no cambiara el significado, pero mi observación no es necesariamente cierta.

Sé que el tiempo imperfecto es para acciones incompletas, habituales o indefinidas, descripciones mientras que el pretérito es para acciones completas (tiene un principio y un final). y tiene mucho sentido para muchos de los verbos que veo, pero no para este verbo que estoy discutiendo aquí.

Ejemplo
20 Estas palabras las pronunció en el lugar del tesoro(X), cuando enseñaba en el templo(Y); y nadie lo prendió, porque todavía no había llegado Su hora(Z).

Advertencias a los incrédulos
21 Entonces Jesús les dijo de nuevo: «Yo me voy, y me buscarán(AA), y ustedes morirán en su pecado(AB); adonde Yo voy, ustedes no pueden ir». 22 Por eso los judíos(AC) decían: «¿Acaso se va a suicidar, puesto que dice: “Adonde Yo voy, ustedes no pueden ir(AD)”?».

23 Y Jesús les decía: «Ustedes son de abajo, Yo soy de arriba(AE); ustedes son de este mundo(AF), Yo no soy de este mundo(AG). 24 Por eso les dije que morirán en sus pecados; porque si no creen que Yo soyd, morirán en sus pecados(AI)».

25 «¿Tú quién eres?», le preguntaron. Jesús les contestó: «¿Qué les he estado diciendo desde el principio[e]? 26 Tengo mucho que decir y juzgar de ustedes, pero Aquel que me envió es veraz(AJ); y Yo, las cosas que oí de Él, estas digo al mundo(AK)».